# Spotify iOS SDK Beta 6 error on SPTAudioStreamingController construction

Tags: spotify

After upgrading the iOS SDK from Beta 5 to Beta 6 I receive this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SPTAudioStreamingController initWithClientId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a3f15a9740'

The line that seems to give the error is this one:

```
self.player = SPTAudioStreamingController(clientId: "my client id")
```

In Beta 5 it was not necessary to provide the clientId. After the upgrade I added the clientId string and get the error above.

Note that the exact same code (without the clientId argument) worked with Beta 5. I get the same error no matter what string I provide. Is this a SDK related bug? SDK in Swift? Or do I have to do additional things after upgrading to Beta 6?

Comment: I think you should check the [issues page for the GitHub repo](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues) and add a new one if you see that nobody has reported it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading Xcode (6.2) and the Spotify iOS SDK (Beta 7) removed the problem. Not sure why.

https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/195

> I made it work now and I assume that there was an error in Beta 6 or
>   maybe in the previous Xcode version. I still think that the errors are
>   a bit misleading so I decided to write what happened for me.
>
> After upgrading to iOS SDK Beta 7 and upgrading Xcode to version 6.2 I
>   created a new project in swift. Writing var a =
>   SPTAudioStreamingController() created an error saying "...use
>   initWithClientId".
>
> I assumed I should try this instead var a =
>   SPTAudioStreamingController.initWithClientId("client-id-string") but
>   this showed another error saying the method doesn't exist.
>
> I was confused for a while since I forgot to add the client ID in the
>   constructor. This is how it should be: var a =
>   SPTAudioStreamingController(clientId: "client-id-string")
>
> I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for pointing it out. I updated the answer. I believe the current format is according to the guidelines.